# Android - Disable wifiManager.disconnect() user Popup

Tags: android, wifimanager

I try to connect with an AP directly using WifiManger, but I don't know how disable the user popup, every time to call wifiManager.disconnect().

```
public void Connect_To_AP(String SSID, String pass)
    {
        String networkSSID = SSID;
        String networkPass = pass;

        peripheralTextView.append("Connecting to AP: " + SSID + "\n");

        //1.- Create a Wifi Configuration
        WifiConfiguration wconf = new WifiConfiguration();
        wconf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain ssid in quotes

        //2.- Configure Network Security Type
        // FOR WEP
        //conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
        //conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
        //conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        //conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);

        // FOR WPA
        wconf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";

        // FOR OPEN
        //conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

        // 3.- Add Configuration to a Wifi_Manager
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(wconf);

        //4.- Enable and Connect.        
        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list )
        {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\""))
            {
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I disable the change wifi AP user PorUp??

Answer (score 0):

..... I find the problem.
Is a phone permissions issue, not from code.
The first time that I execute the App in a Android Studio debugger I select "Ask" permisions.
Now. I change the "Change wifi conectivity" permission to "Always", and now works fine as I expected, neither show the pop up permission.